# Firestore: Storage Architecture much more fields or documents ? in Android Sensor App

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app collects some sensor data from user's phone and send this data periodically to Firestore. Main problem is, I'm newbie at Firestore for this reason I couldn't decide which method is better to storage data. I designed two structure to collect data. First structure storages data on multiple documents and each documents refers only one sensor data fields.

[image: First Structure]

Other method is defined as only one documents that is name created with its "user.getUID()", and contains all sensor data in multiple fields in the same document.

[image: Second Structure]

Which method is better to storage multiple sensor data? Or thanks for any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore documents have a limit of 1MB in size. Given that, I would recommend you use a collection and have each sensor reading be a new document. Otherwise you might run into that 1MB limit.

Please see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: Thanks for answer, its help me too much.

Comment: @EKREMYİĞİT There's the [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document) library that can always help you check against the maximum 1 MiB quota.